# Do not allow the parent div to expand when hidden child div is shown

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making a little menu and I'm trying to figure out how to **NOT** have the parent div expand when the child gets un-hidden.

In the example below, notice when you mouseover the MENUS the `catItemWrapper` div gets shown.
Numbers 1 & 3 are fine, but when you mouseover the MENU TWO it expands the top div as inside one of the menu items has more text.

I'm trying to figure out how to not have the `catWrapper` div expand with the `catItemWrapper` div.

http://jsfiddle.net/vyyNW/

What am I not doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/VfVt7/)***

Allowing the element which stretches the parent to be positioned absolutely will remove it from the page flow and as a result prevent it from resizing the parent.

Set the catitemwrapper to be `position:absolute;`. Doing this makes the margin-left on the catitem show, so you should remove it.

```
.catItemWrapper { position: absolute; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your .catWrapper rules by adding `position:relative` and add a new rule for `catItemWrapper`

```
.catWrapper {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    position:relative;
}
.catItemWrapper{
    position:absolute;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vyyNW/5/)**

Comment: Is the `position: relative` even needed if you aren't giving `top`, `left`, etc. to the child?

Comment: @JamesMontagne - nah, just habit. Doesn't do any harm and prevent surprises if there is a need to change the position.

Answer (score 0):

You want to give your sub-item wrapper (`.catItemWrapper'`) an absolute positioning. You can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/vyyNW/2/. This can be easily done with purely CSS, too. Try using something like below for simpler, cleaner code.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        1
        <ul>
            <li>1.1</li>
            <li>1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        2
        <ul>
            <li>2.1</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        3
        <ul>
            <li>3.1</li>
            <li>3.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
ul, li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul li { display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 100px; }
ul ul { display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; }
ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

Check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/Y7dZj/

Comment: Thanks, but you went a little off what I was going for.